# Does LeapMotion unity 4.0 still support to detect Tools, such as pencil?

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

Recently I need to use leapmotion to detect hand tools, such as pencils.

However, after I searched it in the tutorial, I found that it seems to deprecate the tool() class in version 3.0. Then, I looked into leapmotion unity 4.0 sdk and found that one description: "The Leap Motion software detects hands, fingers and tools within the tracking area, reporting their positions, orientations, gestures, and motions in frames at the Leap Motion frame rate." But I did not find any related classed or functions about detecting tools.

The released notes of Leapmotion unity is: https://developer.leapmotion.com/releases/?offset=1461365400620; and the sdk of leapmotion unity 4.0 is: https://leapmotion.github.io/UnityModules/class_leap_1_1_frame.html.

I will apprepriate it if anybody could tell me how to fix it. Many thanks.